# How to solve $x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=0$?

Tags: polynomials

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

$x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=0$

What I got to was $x^7+1=0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This equation is far from linear. Please correct your title

Comment: What you got is correct. Now, what about the roots of unity $x^n+1=0$ ?

Comment: I know we have to use eulers formula or de moivre's theorem but I don't know how.

Comment: @Claude: Well, roots of _negative_ unity, really.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. Thanks ! I don't know why but I always say it that way.

Comment: Multiply your equation by $$x+1.$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+&a=*C.factor-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=x^6-x^5%2Bx^4-x^3%2Bx^2-x%2B1&f=Factor.factfunction_x^6-x^5%2Bx^4-x^3%2Bx^2-x%2B1

Comment: Would be nice to see how did you get $x^7+1=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the right expression. $x^7+1=0$

The roots of the equation will **be like** $$x= \cos (\frac{2k\pi}{7})+ i\sin (\frac{2k\pi}{7}) , 0\le k\le6$$

**Note**: Stress on **be like**, this formula will not give you the exact roots. You have to change it a bit to account for the roots of negative unity.

EDIT:  **Complete solution** follows:
$$x^7+1=0$$ or,
$$(x+1)(x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)=0$$
This implies your equation has exactly 1 real root and 3 pairs of complex conjugate roots. 
Hence now I can write 
$$x^7+1=0$$ or,
$$x^7=-1$$ or,
$$x^7=\cos \pi + i\sin \pi = \cos (2k+1)\pi + i\sin (2k+1)\pi , 0 \le k\le 6 $$ or,
$$x=[\cos (2k+1)\pi + i\sin (2k+1)\pi]^{\frac{1}{7}} , 0 \le k\le 6$$ or,
$$x=\cos \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{7}+ i\sin \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{7} , 0 \le k\le 6$$

**From the comment by Macavity**: However,you have a spurious root included - $k=3$ . By multiplying by $x+1$ you introduced this root which is not a root of the original polynomial. So there are no real roots for the polynomial, only complex ones. Hence the final solutions are as follows: $$x=\cos \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{7}+ i\sin \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{7} , 0 \le k\le 6 \,\ \text{and} \,\ k \not = 3$$

Comment: There's one more thing I got a hint that the roots should be same to that of &x^7-1=0& Which I do understand but still how to solve it ahead I have no idea.
Let me try the formula, btw is it de moivre's theorem?

Comment: Yup it is the same formula. And the roots will not be same, but similar.

Comment: May be the hint was wrong, its can't be equal to $x^7-1$, Can you confirm this?

Comment: About your Formula Shouldn't there be an iota with sine?

Comment: $k=0$ doesn't make a root of the original equation.

Comment: Can anyone post the answers so that I can check?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have mentioned that the roots I have written are not the exact roots, they have to be modified by OP.

Comment: @محمداحسانالحق Do you want an answer straightaway? I had limited myself to a hint only. However if you wish, I am coming up with a complete answer.

Comment: @محمداحسانالحق I have updated my post and posted the complete solution. Are you okay with it?

Comment: You have a spurious root included - remove $k=3$ option.  By multiplying by $x+1$ you introduced this root which is **not** a root of the original polynomial.  So there are no real roots for the polynomial, only complex ones...

Comment: @Aniket thanks for the help, yeah I have the solution now.

Comment: @Macavity You're right. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @محمداحسانالحق  Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

$$x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x+1)(x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^7+1=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$

---

This introduces the extraneous root of $x=-1$, so from now on we assume that $x\ne -1$:

---

$$x^7+1=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^7=-1 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^7=e^{\pi i} \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\left(e^{(\pi+2\pi k) i}\right)^{\frac{1}{7}} \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=e^{\frac{1}{7}(\pi+2\pi k) i}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-6$

Answer (score 2):

This equation has the same coefficients read backwards.

There is a technique of solving such equations:

If the degree is odd, then $-1$ is a root, and dividing by $x+1$ gives you an even degree equation with the same property.

For even degree: divide by $x$ to the power half degree, and make the substitution $t=x+\frac{1}{x}$.

In this case we get
$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}-(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})+x+\frac{1}{x}-1=0$$

we have
$$t=x+\frac{1}{x} \\
t^2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2\\
t^3=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+3t$$

Therefore, your equation becomes
$$t^3-3t-t^2+2+t-1=0\\
t^3-t^2-2t+1=0$$

You can solve this by using the cubic formula, and then solve the corresponding quadratics.

Comment: What is this technique called and where can I read more about it? Seems pretty clever.

Comment: @SasQ "Reciprocal equation" if you google it you'll find a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $x$ is a complex number, so it can be put in polar form: That is, denoting $|x|=x\bar{x}=r$, and $\ln(x/|x|)=i\phi$, we have $x=e^{i\phi}r$. Now we compute $-1=x^y=(e^{i\phi}r)^7=r^7e^{7i\phi}$, where the last step used De Moivre's formulat to derived $e^{7i\phi}=(e^{i\phi})^7$. We thus have $1=|-1|=|r^7e^{7i\phi}|=|r|^7(e^{7i\phi}e^{-7i\phi}=r^7$, so $r=1$. By Euler's formula, $e^{7i\phi}=i\sin(7\phi)+cos(7\phi)=-1$, so $sin(7\phi)=0$ and $\cos(7\phi)=-1$, so that $7\phi=n2\pi+\pi$, so $\phi=(2n+1)\pi/7$. This gives us solutions $x=e^{(2n+1)\pi/7}$.

Answer (score -1):

As it can be deduced, the roots are complex.

A simpler approach would be to put x= -t. The roots of the corresponding equation in t will be negative of the roots of the equation in t.

On doing so we end up with
t^7-1=0

Of which the roots are the seventh roots of unity.

Thus the roots of x are the negative of the seventh roots of unity

Edit: this is not nearly written as I was in a hurry(and I don't know to type equations in LaTeX). Apologies for everything.

Comment: One year later you post an answer claiming that solving $t^7 = 1$ is easier than solving $x^7 = -1$. Honestly, do you really believe that this answer should have been posted?

Comment: @AlexM. I suppose I was foolish in posting this answer. I made the grave amateurish mistake of not reading any other answer before posting mine.